# Question about a problem solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let us define $$ \int\limits_E f \, dm = \sup Y( E, f ) $$ where $Y(E,f) = \left\{ \int\limits_E \varphi \, dm: 0 \leq \varphi \leq f \right\}$ where $\varphi$ is a simple function.

Here is the problem

[image]

Here is the solution

[image]

My problem is that why $Y ( A \cup B, f) = Y(A,f) + Y(B, f) \implies \sup Y ( A \cup B, f) \leq \sup Y(A,f) + \sup Y(B, f) $ Isnt this inequality actually an equality? Why is the author trying to show the other direction if we can get equality from the this equality and get the result easily? Can someone clear up this confusion to me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that why $Y ( A \cup B, f) = Y(A,f) + Y(B, f) \implies \sup Y ( A \cup B, f) \leq \sup Y(A,f) + \sup Y(B, f) $(?) Isn(')t this inequality actually an equality?

No it is not.

To see why in a somewhat more general setting, consider some set $S$ and two functions $a:S\to \mathbb R$ and $b:S\to\mathbb R$, and let $A=\sup\{a(s)\mid s\in S\}$ and $B=\sup\{b(s)\mid s\in S\}$.

Then, for every $s$ in $S$, $a(s)\leqslant A$ and $b(s)\leqslant A$ hence $a(s)+b(s)\leqslant A+B$. This holds for every $s$ in $S$ hence $\sup\{a(s)+b(s)\mid s\in S\}\leqslant A+B$.

On the other hand, consider $S=\{0,1\}$ and $a(s)=-b(s)=(-1)^s$. Then $A=B=1$ but $\sup\{a(s)+b(s)\mid s\in S\}=0$, which is strictly less than $A+B=2$.

The fact that may prevent $\sup\{a(s)+b(s)\mid s\in S\}$ to be equal to $A+B$ is that $a$ and $b$ may be close to their respective suprema $A$ and $B$ *at different points*.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR EXPLANATION!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. (An advice: try to avoid all-caps messages, even to indicate your enthusiasm...)